# "show X more comments" doesn't work unless the webpage is seemingly completely loaded

Tags: bug, comments

I live in the land of Slow Computers and Internet. My issue is that clicking "show X more comments" does NOT show X more comments when clicked before the *entire* web page is loaded. This often means that I have to sit for thirty seconds for the content to come down the pipe in the background.

This was noticed on [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Not sure if it applies to other Stack Exchanges.

Comment: Could you please add that URL where you are clicking "show X more comments"

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23210/hacker-utility-space-efficient-embedding-a-file-into-jpeg-file-container . Noticed on my own question posed to the site.

Comment: It's loads perfectly for me without repainting the whole page. Hope some others can help.